# Why does Firefox break on a letter and Chrome (properly) breaks on a word?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

Here is a site: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/about-amp.html

When running Chrome, a page looks like this:
[image: Chrome image of web page]

Sentences break on words.

However, when running Firefox the page looks like this:
[image: Firefox image of web page]

In Firefox, sentences break on letters. This happens even when Zoom is set to different percents. Sentences still break on letters; they are just different letters.

**Why is this happening?**

**How to configure Firefox so that sentences break on words?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be the result of `word-break: break-all;`.

**Firefox Inspector:**

[image: Firefox Inspector]

**Chrome Inspector:**

[image: Chrome Inspector]

It appears you are trying to re-override it with `word-break: break-word`, but it's [not listed as a valid value on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) and in either case Firefox does not support that value. You probably just want `word-wrap: break-word`.

Comment: TY!. We don't have control over this document, but can control ones that emulate this document. We'll reset for docs under our control.

Comment: Modification works as you advised. Interesting how Google exploits a feature in Chrome that is not supported in Firefox.